# Plane intersecting all the lines

Tags: geometry, 3d

This might sound a bit stupid or ill thought, but I am having trouble visualizing it and proving it.

Given a finite set $L$ of straight lines in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is it always possible to find a plane which intersects all the lines ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A given plane intersects a given line unless the normal-vector of the plane is perpendicular to the line.

Given a finite set of straight lines, for each line find the plane that is perpendicular to that line and goes through the origin. At the end you have a finite number of planes all passing through the origin. Pick any vector that does not go through those planes and pick a plane perpendicular to that vector. That plane will intersect all the lines.

Comment: If a plane's normal-vector is parallel to a line, that line is a normal to the plane and intersects it.

Comment: You mean "unless the normal-vector of the plane is perpendicular to the line", no ?

Comment: Henrik and Yann: Yep, I really mistyped that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: In fact, this argument (together with a bit of measure theory) shows that one can weaken the hypothesis to allow countably infinite collections of lines too.

Comment: @Travis : $\:$ One just needs the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), not measure theory. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 2):

A line and a plane intersect iff the plane's normal vector isn't orthogonal to the line's direction.  Given a finite set of lines, just choose as normal vector any vector that isn't orthogonal to any direction of the lines.